# Select and Sort ip addresses in lexicographical order

Tags: bash, shell

I am using the below command to sort all ip addresses in lexicographical order.

```
find /root/data -type f -exec grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" {} \; | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2}'
```

I should get this expected output:

```
0.0.0.0
127.0.0.1
127.0.49.1
127.0.64.1
127.65.64.1
127.98.0.1
128.128.4.11
128.57.107.76
128.68.4.11
128.96.107.55
128.99.107.55
128.99.58.55
15.128.4.65
26.56.4.23
67.128.4.11
7.7.7.8
74.0.65.76
77.255.255.254
```

Output of Find command:

```
127.0.0.1
128.99.107.55
128.128.4.11
74.0.65.76
15.128.4.65
0.0.0.0
127.65.64.1
127.0.64.1
127.0.0.1
128.57.107.76
67.128.4.11
7.7.7.8
127.98.0.1
128.96.107.55
128.68.4.11
127.0.49.1
128.99.58.55
77.255.255.254
26.56.4.23
```

How can I sort this as per the expected output.

Comment: how about: `find ... | cut -f2- | sort -u`

Comment: Should there be 2 127.0.0.1 ip addresses in the unsorted list?

Comment: @vgersh99 No, that dint work.

Comment: @ColeTierney, it's really not about the duplicates, but 7.7.7.8 should be in the 3rd line from last.

Comment: @Patrick Can you update your question with the output of your find command? I'll use that as input while experimenting.

Comment: @ColeTierney updated the question.

Comment: @Patrick Using the output of your find command, I still get 7.7.7.8 in the third line from the last. I'm using sort (GNU coreutils) 8.29.

Comment: I tried Apple's v2.3 sort and my results are the same with 7.7.7.8 third from last.

Answer (score 0):

The the `-t` option tells `sort` to use period as a field separator. The `-k` options tell sort which fields to use. Note: to sort by numeric order, add the `-n` option.

```sh
sort -t. -k1 -k2 -k3 -k4 unsorted
```

Output:

```
0.0.0.0
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.49.1
127.0.64.1
127.65.64.1
127.98.0.1
128.128.4.11
128.57.107.76
128.68.4.11
128.96.107.55
128.99.107.55
128.99.58.55
15.128.4.65
26.56.4.23
67.128.4.11
7.7.7.8
74.0.65.76
77.255.255.254
```

Comment: Thanks, do you mean this way:
find ... | sort -t\. -k1 -k2 -k3 -k4 | uniq -c | awk '{print $2}'

Comment: @Patrick no you can simply pipe your ip list to the sort command or add a filename with the ip list after the sort command as an argument

Comment: There is no reason to backslash the dot, per se.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks you're right. Just a regex habit I guess

Comment: @Patrick I just reread your original question. You _would_ need your original find command to generate the list of ip numbers. Just pipe that to the sort command in my answer. You will not need `uniq` and `awk`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ColeTierney tried this, but I get the same output not the expected -> 
`find /root/data -type f -exec grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" {} \; | sort -t. -k1 -k2 -k3 -k4`

Answer (score 0):

Redirect your output through the pipeline `sort -d`.

```
find /root/data -type f -exec grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" {} \; | 
sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2}' | sort -d
```

Comment: `sort -d` seems to put `7.7.7.8` after `77.255.255.254`

Comment: @Philippe: this seems to be the dictionnary order and is probably the same as what you were asking for when you spoke about lexicographical order. For me too, it is strange...

Comment: I meant that's not expected by OP.

Answer (score 0):

would something like enforcing radix sort work ?

```
LC_ALL=C sort --radixsort
```

and that's it. no need to specify delimiter -t, fields -k, or stable -s

(ps : those are only BSD sort command as seen on macOS. Not too familiar with GNU sort myself)